# Splitting Form Results Evenly between 2 recipients

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, sendmail

I need to split the form results from a contact form evenly between two recipients.

E.g. First contact form goes to Recipient 1, next one goes to Recipient 2, next one goes to Recipient 1 etc.

Just wondering what's the best way to do this using php, mysql and/or javascript.

I'm sure this question has been asked before but a detailed search has produced no results.

Comment: I would store a "last_recipient" ID somewhere in the database and when receiving the form results (per POST?) deciding which recipient's next. After deciding change the value in the databse.

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML hidden input types. Like so,

```
<input type="hidden" name="recipient" value="1, 2, or 3 etc." />
```

Hidden inputs are not visible on the page! They just help the programmer identify a particular stuff.

In PHP, look for the defined hidden value and send the message to the respected recipient. Do something like,

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['recipient'])) {

$theRecipient = $_POST['recipient']; //we want to know who will be the recipient

... //Perform your code!


}
```

?>